# How to find documents with duplicated attributes in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following documents stored in my MongoDB database (let's say collection `products`):

```
{
   a: "test1",
   c: "data1"
},
{
   a: "test2",
   c: "data2"
},
{
   a: "test3",
   c: "data1"
},
{
   a: "test4",
   c: "data3"
},
{
   a: "test5",
   c: "data1"
},
{
   a: "test6",
   c: "data3"
},
```

How can I query all documents that have attribute `c` duplicated (or triplicated...)? In the example data, the query should return `test1, test3, test4, test5 and test6` documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by grouping on `c` and then getting the groups with more than one in the group:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$c', count: {$sum: 1}, docs: {$push: '$$ROOT'}}},
    {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}
])
```